# If $(1-x^3)^n=\sum_{r=0}^{n} a_r x^r (1-x)^{3n-2r}$, then prove that $a_r=\binom{n}{r} 3^r$.

Tags: combinatorics, polynomials, binomial-coefficients

If $$(1-x^3)^n=\sum_{r=0}^{n} a_r x^r (1-x)^{3n-2r}$$ then prove that  $$a_r=\binom{n}{r} 3^r.$$

I have factored $1-x^3=(1-x)(1+x+x^2)$ and cancelled out one factor $(1-x)^n$ from both sides after which we get

$$(1+x+x^2)^n=\sum_{r=0}^{n} a_r x^r (1-x)^{2n-2r}.$$

Any clue here?

Comment: I would do this by induction on $n$ unless there is a clever trick that one could use.

Comment: $1+x+x^2=3x+(1-2x+x^2)=3x+(1-x)^2$

Comment: awesome thanks great trick

Answer (score 2):

I begin with the answer :

$\sum_0^n \binom{n}{r} 3^r x^r (1-x)^{3n-2r} =
 \sum_0^n \binom{n}{r} (3x)^r ((1-x)^2)^{n-r} (1-x)^n$

which is $(1-x)^n ((3x) + (1-x)^2)^n = (1-x)^n (1+x+x^2)^n$

I tried to make something like $\binom{n}{r} A^r B^{n-r}$